# Node js using mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Please I am having error:

> User.findOne is not a function

In my code How do I resolve it?

```
User.findOne({email: email})
  .then(user)
```

Comment: Can you put some codes that you tried. it will help finding error.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We don't know why `findOne` isn't a function because we don't know what `User` is.

Answer (score 0):

User has to be a model object if  you are using sequelize. Only then the sequelize functions could work.